# Processing - Managing ArrayLists

Tags: processing

I'm trying to manage this `ArrayList`. Basically I have an `ArrayList` of `PVector` objects - in my code there are two pairs of `(x,y)` variables coming into the array. I would like to know how to manage the two pairs separately. I need to know which one is `(x1,y1)` and which one is `(x2,y2)`, and possibly name them. How can I do this?

```java
Blob(float x, float y) {
  minx = x;
  miny = y;
  maxx = x;
  maxy = y;
  points = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  points.add(new PVector(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [Creating Classes](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve based on your question, but if you would like to create 2 `PVector` objects from your `blob` function and add them to your `ArrayList`, then add 2 more arguments to the function. For example:

```java
void blob(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  minx = x1;
  miny = y1;
  maxx = x2;
  maxy = y2;
  points = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  points.add(new PVector(minx, miny));
  points.add(new PVector(maxx, maxy));
}
```

You can then use the **index** of the `ArrayList` to identify the two `PVector` objects, and to name them you can assign them to variables. For example:

```java
PVector firstPoint = points.get(0);
PVector secondPoint = points.get(1);
```